# How to preload data with Core-Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

How to preload data, such as I slid to the border in January 2015, if the slide forward, then it displays the data in December 2014. @Eric Skroch

Comment: can you please elaborate your question with code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can load as much plot data as you want at any time. It will only display the values that fit in the plot space.